# How do I edit a nav bar to make the background not invisible?

Tags: css

I can't seem to figure out why the background of my nav bar is invisible until I start scrolling.

I want it to be a solid colour the entire time.

This is the code:

```
#header {
padding: 20px 0px 10px!important;
transition: 0.5s;}

#header .logo img {
max-width: 250px;
max-height: 125px;}

.is-sticky #header {
z-index: 999999;
background: #404040;
border-bottom: 1px solid {{ baseColor }};}

#header .navigation {
max-width: auto;
max-height; auto;}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you also add html code to your post?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you have some js in your site that adds the class `is-sticky` to one of the parent elements of your `header` when you scroll.

Try moving the `background: #404040;` from `.is-sticky #header` to the `#header` style:

```css
#header {
  padding: 20px 0px 10px!important;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: #404040;
}
#header .logo img {
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 125px;
}
.is-sticky #header {
  z-index: 999999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid {{ baseColor }};
}
```

The above assumes `#header` is the navbar you are talking about